One of the security cameras failed
I have 4 security cameras connected to a DVR via cables that have been working fine for years. However, after a recent power outage, one of the cameras stopped working. On the screen connected to the DVR, 3 cameras are functioning normally, but one shows only a black screen. At night, I can still see the infrared LEDs on the faulty camera, indicating that it has power, but there is no video feed to the DVR.
I had a spare camera, so I decided to test it before installing it. I connected the new camera, and the video feed worked. After this, I replaced the faulty camera with the new one, but after the installation, the new camera also stopped working. Like the previous camera, it still has lights at night but no video.
To troubleshoot, I wanted to check if the old camera had failed or if there was an issue with the cables. I made a short cable to connect the old camera directly to the DVR, but it still didn’t work.
What could be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

could be the DVR

@jsotola no, it is not the case. I swapped camera connectors on DVR and the failing camera is always the same one.

Lost video or data connection?  You didn't tell us whether this is a hardwired camera or a webcam.

@keshlam given "I made a short cable" I would assume it's hardwired.  Is it possible to be dual mode?

It sounds like you've done all the work needed to diagnose a faulty cable, (or possibly a faulty power supply if the power supply is not coming from the DVR)
